# Cannot run "vagrant up" in PhpStorm 6 in command line

Tags: vagrant, phpstorm

I am trying to launch my Vagrant directly from Phpstorm 6 but I am not able to find the command (Windows).

Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8aUA.png

Is there anything I could do to make it works ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created an **alias** for `vagrant` in **"Settings | Command Line Tool Support"** ?

Command Line Support Tool does not know what `vagrant` is, so it tries to execute whole command as is. The problem is -- proper name of app should be `vagrant.bat` (or `vagrant.cmd` -- do not remember) -- *IDE does not add .bat/.exe/etc automatically like DOS/Windows does.*

So either use `vagrant.bat up` command instead .. or (which is better) create an alias.

---

**P.S.**
PhpStorm **v7** will search for .bat/.cmd/.exe/etc in your PATH if exact command cannot be found. Still -- making an alias is the best/safest way to go here in Command Line Tools.

Answer (score 0):

An excerpt from: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/vagrant.html

> Make sure that the parent folders of the following executable files
>   are added to the system PATH variable:
>
> ```
> vagrant.bat or vagrant from your Vagrant installation. This should be done automatically by the Vagrant installer.
> ```

If you've installed Vagrant the standard way then just restart the command prompt itself or phpStorm so it reloads the PATH. Else just find that bat file and run it manually to see if it works or better add the path to the system PATH var.